# org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.IssueListener not found in sonar-scanner-engine-shaded:6.7

Tags: sonarqube

Having the following setup:

- https://github.com/TouK/sputnik 1.8.0
- SonarQube 6.7
- Jenkins 2.36

When executing the following Post step in Jenkins

```
sputnik --conf sputnik.properties --changeId xxxxxx --revisionId xxxxx
```

I'm getting the error

```
DEBUG: Extract sonar-runner-batch in temp...
DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
DEBUG: Download: http://localhost:9000/sonar/batch_bootstrap/index
DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
DEBUG: Execution getVersion
DEBUG: Execution start
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/IssueListener
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.DefaultBatchFactory.createBatch(DefaultBatchFactory.java:44)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.start(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doStart(EmbeddedRunner.java:251)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.start(EmbeddedRunner.java:187)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.start(EmbeddedRunner.java:182)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.execute(EmbeddedRunner.java:209)
    at pl.touk.sputnik.processor.sonar.SonarRunner.run(SonarRunner.java:62)
    at pl.touk.sputnik.processor.sonar.SonarProcessor.process(SonarProcessor.java:49)
    at pl.touk.sputnik.engine.ReviewRunner.review(ReviewRunner.java:25)
    at pl.touk.sputnik.engine.Engine.run(Engine.java:40)
    at pl.touk.sputnik.Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.IssueListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:82)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

Digging a little deeper I had to notice that Sputnik 1.8.0 is using `sonar-runner-api-2.5.1.jar` that contains `DefaultBatchFactory.createBatch` which fails due to the following declaration:

```
public class Compatibility {   
    static class IssueListenerAdapter 
        implements org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.IssueListener {
    }
}
```

As far as I can see `org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-scanner-engine-shaded:6.5` was still supporting that `IssueListener` while `org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-scanner-engine-shaded:6.6` is not anymore. Furthermore I cannot find any newer version of `sonar-runner-api-2.5.1.jar` which Sputnik could use. Do you have any idea how this issue is to be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sonar-runner-api-2.5.1` is not supported anymore. Please upgrade to a more recent version. Note that artifactId has been changed to `sonar-scanner-api`.
See available versions:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/

Comment: Thank you so far for your fast reply. I created a pull request on sputnik (https://github.com/TouK/sputnik/pull/173) to follow your advice.